# CDH 5.2 Error starting NodeManager-Service NodeManager failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

```
2014-11-21 19:05:37,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://hadoop-master.nycloudlab.internal:8020/user/admin/.staging/job_1415362431963_0311/libjars/hbase-hadoop-compat.jar(->/yarn/nm/usercache/admin/filecache/1513/hbase-hadoop-compat.jar) transitioned from INIT to LOCALIZED
2014-11-21 19:05:37,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Recovering application application_1415362431963_0302
2014-11-21 19:05:37,554 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1415362431963_0302 transitioned from NEW to INITING
2014-11-21 19:05:37,578 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.recoverContainer(ContainerManagerImpl.java:289)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.recover(ContainerManagerImpl.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:492)
2014-11-21 19:05:37,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Applications still running : [application_1415362431963_0302]
2014-11-21 19:05:37,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService waiting for pending aggregation during exit
2014-11-21 19:05:37,589 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.recoverContainer(ContainerManagerImpl.java:289)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.recover(ContainerManagerImpl.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:492)
2014-11-21 19:05:37,590 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
2014-11-21 19:05:37,591 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
2014-11-21 19:05:37,591 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2014-11-21 19:05:37,591 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.recoverContainer(ContainerManagerImpl.java:289)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.recover(ContainerManagerImpl.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:492)
2014-11-21 19:05:37,593 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: Found that there there is Jira issue reported for this
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2816

Fixed this issue by deleting /tmp/hadoop-yarn/yarn-nm-recovery

LevelDB never writes in place: it always appends to a log file, or merges existing files together to produce new ones. So an OS crash will cause a partially written log record (or a few partially written log records). LevelDB recovery code uses checksums to detect this and will skip the incomplete records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue by deleting /tmp/hadoop-yarn/yarn-nm-recovery. LevelDB never writes in place.
It always appends to a log file.